# Can't use navigator.camera.getPicture on iOS phonegap adobe build

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, phonegap-build

I have been looking for hours now and can't get my phonegap app (compiled by adobe phonegap build) and I fear I am missing something about phonegap. I have added the following lines to the config.xml file:

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
<feature name="Camera">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCamera" />
</feature>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera"/>
```

I try to take the picture using the following code:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(function(image) {callback("data:image/jpeg;base64," + image)}, cameraFail, { quality: 49 });
```

I am testing it by running it on an iPad2 running iOS 7. I've created a rudimentary inapp console and the problem appears to be that navigator.camera does not exist. Thanks for reading hope you can help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With help from another answer it lead me to realize what I had done wrong so i'll post for anyone else that is in the same boat.

I hadn't included a reference to cordova.js which should be done just by adding a normal script tag like this:

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

I hadn't included it as I did not have the file cordova.js. What I did not realize is when using the adobe Phonegap Build service the file is added automatically and I did not need it in my source directory, just to include the tag.

Comment: In the head of the index file

Answer (score 2):

Installing plugins for PhoneGap can be difficult.

Do you have the following functions in your code?

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
 }); 

function onSuccess(imageData) {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}

function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

Your config.xml seems ok.

Also, check the following links:

https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/242

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/tree/fed4f2280d786cabb24641eb6ce686acf98d0a94 
(Contains test folder so you can test it on your device)

Comment: Thanks for checking my code vonBerg your confirmation and link lead me to realize my mistake